# How to generate all combinations and store in a sparse matrix?

Tags: python, combinations, sparse-matrix

Let's say I have 5 different products and I want to know all combinations a customer can add to their basket with basket size of 4. In other words, I need all 4-product combinations from the 5 available products. There are 5 possible 4-product combinations. I'd like to store the combinations in a matrix/dataframe in this format (using a "1" to indicate the product is included):

| ComboID | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 | Product 4 | Product 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

This trouble I am running into is that I have to create all 15-product combinations from 37 different products. This results in 9,364,199,760 combinations and I run out of memory. My initial thinking is to store this in a sparse matrix since I'm just storing 1's and 0's, but I am having trouble implementing this. Ideas?

**EDIT**: What we are doing is once we have the combinations, we iterate through each row and calculate a score for that given combination. So we end up with a dataframe of combinationID and Score which is my ultimate goal. So since sparse matrix doesn't seem to make sense, my next thought would be to build a combo, calculate its score, store in a dataframe, then build next combo, calculate its score, store in a dataframe, etc. Not sure the most efficient way to do this though. (also, I'll upload OP with this info)

Comment: 40.5% non-zero entries doesn't strike me as particularly sparse...

Comment: `sparse` won't help with memory unless the proportion of 1s to 0s is something like 5%, i.e many more zeros than ones.

Comment: Why do you want that matrix, btw?

Comment: Ah, that makes sense about sparse matrix. What we are doing is once we have the combinations, we iterate through each row and calculate a score for that given combination. So we end up with a dataframe of combinationID and Score which is my ultimate goal. So since sparse matrix doesn't seem to make sense, my next thought would be to build a combo, calculate its score, store in a dataframe, then build next combo, calculate its score, store in a dataframe, etc. Not sure the most efficient way to do this though. (also, I'll upload OP with this info)

Comment: Why do you want all billions of scores?

Comment: @KellyBundy, I think I see where you are going. I technically don't need to keep them all. I need to keep the ones that hit a certain score threshold. For example, the score can be between 0 and 1, and I may want to keep only scores that are >0.9.

Comment: Looks like we're getting closer to your actual ultimate goal. If we knew what it is, maybe we could help much better...

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with billions of combinations, you're going to start running into hardware issues in terms of size. Here are two suggestions for approaches that might help you:

1. Try reducing the number of combinations you have to deal with by using Design of Experiments. You may not need to test every possible combination if you can build a model that predicts the optimal combination: https://www.isixsigma.com/tools-templates/design-of-experiments-doe/design-experiments-%E2%90%93-primer/
2. If you really need to check every combination, try using Cloud Computing. If you can spin up 1000 workers and have them each try some of the combinations, then no one worker will have so much data that their memory is overloaded. Plus, you'll get your results 1000 times faster!
3. Final suggestion, if you have to do it all on one computer: rather than generating a matrix of combinations ahead of time, see if you can write a generator function that takes in the last combination and calculates the next combination. This would mean you only ever need to store the current configuration and the best configuration found so far.

Comment: I think your #3 makes the most sense, since I only need to keep combinations that meet a certain score threshold. Not sure how to construct a generator function for this though.

Comment: @Crescent Python's built in [Itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is probably going to be the easiest way to create a generator/iterator of all the combinations~

Comment: *"you only ever need to store the current configuration and the best configuration found so far'* - Where did they say they only want the single "best" one?

Comment: `itertools.combinations()` is perfect for this.

Comment: @code-lukas, Yes I've been testing `itertools.combinations()`. But how can I generate/loop through the combos one at a time rather than storing the entire object in a variable?

Comment: @Crescent *"how can I generate/loop through the combos one at a time"* - Just do exactly that?

Comment: @KellyBundy, perhaps my understanding of python objects is the issue. If I create a variable like this: `myCombos = itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5],3)`, are all the combinations being stored in memory? Or are they created on the fly when I use a FOR loop to loop through the items?

Comment: @Crescent On the fly.

Comment: i.e. `for combination in itertools.combinations(range(4), 2):` works. Or you just store it in a variable like you proposed.

Comment: KellyBundy, code-lukas, thank you for your help.